# First letter capital in string c#

Tags: c#, uppercase, letter

I am trying to change the first letter of a string to capital

I saw other questions on this but even when I apply what they've said I still can't manage the correct result.

```
public string FirstLetterToUpper(string str)
{
    if (str == null)
        return null;

    if (str.Length > 1)
        return char.ToUpper(str[0]) + str.Substring(1);

    return str.ToUpper();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = "test text";
    CapitalizeFirstLetter(label1.Text);        
}
```

Instead of outputting

```
Test text
```

it remains

```
test text
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `label1.Text = CapitalizeFirstLetter("test text");`

Comment: Do you need to be able to deal with all of unicode? In general you can't take the first UTF-16 code-unit and uppercase it, since one symbol may consist of sever code-units and even several code-points.

Comment: Where is the `CapitalizeFirstLetter` method? If that's implemented in this way everything is fine and should work: `label1.Text=FirstLetterToUpper(input);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to assign the result (and use the correct method name)

```
label1.Text = FirstLetterToUpper("test text");
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not making use of the return value of your `FirstLetterToUpper` method.  Try this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = "test text";
    label1.Text = FirstLetterToUpper(label1.Text);        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a web-based or a desktop-based application.  However, I believe your issue stems from a poor deceleration. For instance, your label has a proper value but you aren't *reassigning* the value.

```
label1.Text = CapitalizeFirstLetter(label1.Text);
```

The reason it isn't working is because you aren't changing the label's value, you leave it as: `test text`.  That is why your issue occurred.

However, you could make it a bit more readable by doing:

```
label1.Text = CapitalizeFirstLetter("text text");
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers explain your error (you need to reassign the value obtained by your method to your label), but you could also change the code that capitalizes to use a built-in method

```
string[] words = label1.Text.Split();
words[0] = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(words[0]);
label1.Text = string.Join(" ", words);
```

This is more resilient to globalization issues.